# Pointwise convergence of a succession of matrices

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence

I am facing an example that I am not able to understand at all. It says the the limit of a pointwise convergent sequence of positive semi-definite metrices is positive semi-definite. Basically, I do not understand how to use the pointwise convergence for a matrix, that is, I do not know a definition that is general enough to be applied to that case, and I was not able to find it anywhere.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition**. A sequence of $n\times n$ matrices $(A_k)$ converges to matrix $A$ if for all $i,j=1,\dots,n$ we have $A_k(i,j) \to A(i,j)$. Here I use parentheses to denote the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix.

To show $A$ is positive semidefinite, we must check that for every vector $x$ the following holds:
$$x^TAx\ge 0\tag{1}$$
Since each $A_k$ is positive definite, we have 
$$x^TA_kx\ge 0\tag{2}$$
It remains to pass to the limit $k\to \infty$ to obtain (1) from (2). Indeed, the formula in (2) is just a finite sum: 
$$x^TA_kx = \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_k(i,j)x_ix_j$$
in which $x_ix_j$ are fixed coefficients. The limit as $k\to\infty $ is (1).